# How can ground bounce be simulated by lumped elements?

Tags: signal, ground

I'm trying to demonstrate myself and to some friends how ground bouncing occurs. Is there a way to use lumped circuit with some compients to demsotare it? Something similar to simulating inductive spikes caused by a large inductive load.

Can someone provide a simplistic representative circuit which demonstrates the phenomenon?

Comment: All you need is a CMOS inverter or two and the addition of some trace impedance in their supply lines. That is probably less than 10 components.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9flGY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Notice the onchip 1 Ohm is a valuable dampening agent.

As are the Rout of the two FETs, as they strive to charge and discharge the 100pF CLoad.

As are the ESR of the offchip VDD capacitors.

There should be lots of ringing in the 100MHz to 200MHz region. Why? Because companies **ADD** more VDD and GND pins when Fring is LOW; low frequency ringing causes SHMOO holes, where the MCU will fail to properly clock at some clock frequencies and VDD combinations.